# What does 'experiment proper' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does *proper* mean in this context?

> "Perhaps not surprisingly, many participants initially struggled to recognize the alleged subtle difference between the two conditions, and so were required to complete more than ten thousand trials **before moving on to the experiment proper**."

Comment: ..before moving  on to the proper (real) experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See definition 1.1: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proper

An experiment *proper* is the  experiment *in its true form*.

In other words, the participants had to complete many trials (in something of a practice experiment) before moving on to do the *actual* experiment.

I hear this type of usage most often when talking about metropolitan areas. For example, "Boston" could refer to the city itself as well as the surrounding metropolitan area, while "Boston proper" refers to just the actual city itself, excluding the surrounding area.